# String of ISO-8601 datetime to number of seconds in Java

Tags: java, datetime, isodate

How do I convert a string of ISO-8601 datetime (ex: `2012-05-31T13:48:04Z`) to number of seconds( `10 digit integer`) using Java?

Comment: A number of seconds since when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
String DateStr="2012-05-31T13:48:04Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date d=sdf.parse(DateStr);
System.out.println(d.getTime());
```

**output** 1338452284000

*From the comments of OP*
getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

Comment: Is the above output in milliseconds?

Comment: I don't see where the *10-digit integer* is which the OP is looking for. Also, the OP wants the seconds and not the milliseconds. Plus this would give the no. of seconds since `Epoch`. You need to mention quite a few things in here mate! :)

Comment: @raHul - Yeah, it is, indeed!

Comment: @R.J I was on the way of editing few things.As you know we are not supposed to give the complete code so I just gave an example likely a hint.If you say then i will provide the entire code.

Comment: @JqueryLearner - I did not say that you need to provide the entire code(you did already provide a lot though). You could have mentioned that it is in millis and that it needs to be converted to int. Also, the fact that it gives the milli/seconds since Epoch, etc.

Comment: @R.J Thanks for your suggestion,I have edited my answer.Thanks again for suggesting for better answer

Answer (score 1):

using `SimpleDateFormat` and use format like `yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss 'Z'`

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2012-05-31T13:48:04Z" )
       .getEpochSecond()
```

> 1338472084

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/MI5b6S).

## Using java.time

Much easier with the java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Easy to parse your input string as the java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2012-05-31T13:48:04Z" ) ;
```

I am guessing that by “seconds” you meant the number of seconds elapsed since the beginning of 1970 UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). The `Instant` class can tell you the number of seconds since that [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

> 1338472084

Beware of data loss, obviously. You are ignoring any fractional second that may be present in your date-time value.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).